# Terminal user and guest account logged into GUI interacting with each other

Tags: command-line, ssh, notification, guest-session

***What we have:***  I want to connect to a remote Linux box via SSH with an account with superuser privileges. This Linux machine has one current logged in user who is using a GUI on a guest account.

***What I've tried to do:*** I want to send this guest-user a message from the terminal that will pop up on their screen. The `write` command does **not** work; it says the user is not logged in. I tried both "guest" and "guest-Jt" (which is the current temporary name of the guest per the `w` command".

***What I want to do:*** How can I write this guest user a pop-up message from the terminal with my superuser? And how can they write me back without going into a terminal themselves?

Answer (score 1):

The temporary user, that is created when you enter an Ubuntu guest session, has the name format `guest-XXXXXX`, i.e. six characters after the dash. Try the `users` command instead of the `w` command.